# Java POI: trouble executing user-defined function

Tags: java, excel, excel-formula, apache-poi

In a cell, a user has put:

```
=SHA256function(K4)
```

And defined the SHA256function function in the VBAProject Module.

```
Public Function SHA256function(sMessage As String)

Dim clsX As Class1
Set clsX = New Class1

SHA256function = clsX.SHA256(sMessage)

Set clsX = Nothing

End Function
```

The POI FormulaEvaluator fails to evaluate the cell with the following error message:

```
FormulaParseException : Name 'SHA256function' is completely unknown in the current workbook
```

Can someone help solve this issue ?

I'm using poi-3.10-FINAL

Denis

Comment: Can you do a Java implementation of the function? Apache POI is completely unable to process VBA!